# Spring - Thymeleaf - Tomcat -> can not process UTF-8 character correctly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, utf-8, thymeleaf

I am trying to display UTF-8 character in Spring-MVC web page.

utf-8 values are coming from the database. I have already converted my database into utf-8.

web services I have written is displaying the values as expected but, in the web page it is not showing the correct value.

below is my spring configuration, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

I am using thymeleaf as a templating engine:

**Thymeleafe configuration:**

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>
```

I have also added CharecterEncodingFilter in my web.xml as below:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

I have also tried changing the server.xml in tomcat configuration:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
```

but it is not working as expected:
it is showing me ???? in place of the actual value. and the strange thing is when I use the Unicode value of the actual value then it is working.

can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong or missing.

**Update Ans config using XML**

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>
```

I have to set the characterEncoding in `ThymeleafViewResolver` instead of ServletContextTemplateResolver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to add utf to thymeleaf view resolver:

```
Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}
```