# Problem with Encoding ????? instead letters

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, gradle

Using: Spring mvc, tomcat, thymeleaf and instagram4j. When i want to display some info from instagram i using instagram4j and retrieve info from instagram4j objects but on pages i have only ????? but in idea console i have good info.
Example
in console: [image]
on the page: [image]
Any acts with encoding didnt good results
Thanks for help

Comment: Are your files in your project and your application configured to use UTF-8?

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes, all project and app configured to use UTF-8

Comment: I see that are cyrillic letters, latin letters display good.

Comment: when i try do some like this ```new String(cyrillic.getBytes("Cp1252"), "Cp1251");```  or this ```new String(cyrillic.getBytes("Cp1251"), "UTF-8");``` in console output the same that on the page '??????'

Answer (score 0):

This answer help [solution of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32894357/11094239)
In mvc config ViewResolver add `resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

```
        @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
```